# Why do I need the SID in my URL?

Tags: magento2, multistore, url, session, cookie

Since I installed my store I see the SID code in my URLs but I don't know why it's there, I found an option in my admin panel to disable it.

[image: Magento 2 SID code in my URL]

Could you explain to me why do I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you don't use a multistore you can disable it!**

This is a good answer to it:

> The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this to track a user's
>   activity within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento
>   powers one website and one store from one installation (database).
>
> Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one
>   installation though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while
>   navigating across these websites/stores.
>
> I think if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent when
>   accessing catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the
>   user's location/state for the current website/store.
>
> If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's
>   safe to disable the SID on the frontend.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304826/2525701).

Comment: i have three websites and three stores within it,but can create products two onlw defaule website view.how can i do it for all websites?with one admin?

Comment: It's a question for a new topic.